# Why do Proto-germanic "-as" nouns have e-grade?

Tags: etymology, greek, germanic-languages, ancient

Why do Proto-germanic "-as" nouns have e-grade (don't have an ablaut like Ancient Greek τρέπ-ω τρόπ-ος, πέκ-ω πόκ-ος, λέχ-ομαι λόχ-ος, φέβ-ομαι φόβ-ος)?

Comment: Likely analogical leveling. There are some with e-grade, which became the -er nouns in German that umlaut the root vowel.